# Range-based for-loop over regex matches?

Tags: c++, c++11

In pre-final drafts of C++11, a range-based for loop could specify the range to iterate over via a pair of iterators.  This made it easy to iterate over all matches for a regular expression.  The ability to specify a range using a pair of iterators was later removed, and it is not present in C++11.  Is there still a straightforward way to iterate over all matches for a particular regular expression?  I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
std::regex begin(" 1?2?3?4* ");
std::regex end;

for(auto& match: std::pair(begin, end)) process(*match);
```

Is there support for this kind of thing in C++11?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with doing it for `std::pair` is that it "works" on a lot of things that aren't valid ranges. Thus causing errors.

C++11 doesn't come with a built-in solution for this. You can use [Boost.Range's `make_iterator_range` facility to build one easily](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html). Then again, it's not exactly difficult to do manually:

```
template<typename T>
class IterRange
{
  T start;
  T end;
public:
  IterRange(const T &start_, const T &end_) : start(start_), end(end_) {}

  T begin() {return start;}
  T end() {return end;}
};

template<typename T> IterRange<T> make_range(const T &start, const T &end) {return IterRange<T>(start, end);}
```

Comment: I would set a default value for end=T() in make_range(). That way istream_iterator-s and indeed regex iterators can be created using a single arg. This is a fairly common idiom.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a pair of iterators to specify the sequence to iterate through. The statement `for(a: c)` in essence iterates through the sequence `[begin(c), end(c))`. So all you need to do is use a `match_results` object or provide suitable `begin` and `end` functions that return one of the regular expression iterator types.

Comment: std::match_results offers begin and end member functions, so that base is already covered.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe - you've lived up to your name. <g> Fixed. Thanks.